# How increase size of two sub images side by side

Tags: graphics, subfloats, minipage, size

I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \subfloat[horizontal mic pairs]{\label{horizontal mic pair 
    combinations}\includegraphics[width=0.81\linewidth] 
    {Text/Images/hyp3_arr1_hor.png}}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \centering
  \subfloat[vertical mic pairs]{\label{Vertical mic pair 
    combinations}\includegraphics[width=0.80\linewidth] 
    {Text/Images/hyp3_arr1_ver.png}}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Mean and standard deviation of absolute difference of 
    geometrical and estimated azimuth and elevation angles for 
    horizontal and vertical microphone pair combinations of 
    microphone array 1 respectively, (a) - (b).}
  \label{fig:hyp3_arr1_hor_ver}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The problem that I am facing these figures are coming very small. I want to increase size of the images. Can anyone help me how can I modify this code?

Comment: Please make your code snippet -- as usual here -- complete and compilable!

Comment: This is my complete code. Actually this is a part of code use to insert two images in a long report

Comment: Well, we need to know which documentclass you use, which packages do you load related to your issue and at last please add `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to your code snippet in your question ...

Comment: The problem might be the double use of `\linewidth` both in `minipage` and `\includegraphics`. The `\linewidth` changes inside the `minipage`! Try using `\textwidth` instead and adjust the factor for the image width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
     \begin{figure}[htb]
     \centering
\subfloat[horizontal mic pairs
          \label{horizontal mic pair combinations}]%
  {\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{Text/Images/hyp3_arr1_hor.png}}
\hfil
\subfloat[vertical mic pairs
          \label{Vertical mic pair combinations}]%
    {\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{Text/Images/hyp3_arr1_ver.png}}
\caption{Mean and standard deviation of absolute difference of geometrical and estimated azimuth and elevation angles for horizontal and vertical microphone pair combinations of microphone array 1 respectively, (a) - (b).}
\label{fig:hyp3_arr1_hor_ver}
    \end{figure}
```

**edit:**

in above *mwe* (minimal working example) are removed `minipage`s (they are superfluous)  and corrected width of included images. images width you can slightly enlarge, for example to `width=0.495` ;-) (with `width=0.5` the gape between images will disappear), or decrease to size which you like to have.

Comment: i need not the figures to touch the border of page. just to increase a size little bit so they are easy to understand

Comment: @AhmadBilal, the size of images is my *mwe*  determined by `includegraphics`'s option `width=...`. you just select this width. however, the sum of the both widths should be les than `\linewidth` (`\textwidth`)

Comment: I have tried to do that. It is showing better results. Thank you for the help

Comment: @AhmadBilal, better result? this is opinion based judgement which is depend of taste of observer or document author ... you just like such appearance what is ok.

Comment: Actually i am trying to play with different width type. Sometimes it gets so bigger that the images dont remain side by side.Sometimes width reduces the size.

Comment: i want to show you the resulting images. How it can be done here?

Comment: edit your question and add your images.